# Перегрузка операторов (+, [], <<) Динамический массив

Tags: c++

Уже несколько часов пытаюсь перегрузить операторы +; []; << . Самостоятельно смог перегрузить оператор декремента(постфиксного и префиксного),который удаляет последний элемент, а эти никак не получаются(
Оператор + по идее должен прибавлять к динамическому массиву новый элемент по порядку;
Оператор [] должен позволять редактировать элемент массива по индексу;
Оператор << выводить весь массив , не разбивая стейтмент.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Array
{
T* arr;
int capacity;
int current;
public:
Array()
{
  arr = new T[1];
  capacity = 1;
  current = 0;
}
 
void push(T data)
    {
        if (current == capacity) {
            T* temp = new T[2 * capacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                temp[i] = arr[i];
            }
            delete[] arr;
            capacity *= 2;
            arr = temp;
    }
        arr[current] = data;
        current++;
    }
    
void push(int data, int index)
    {
            arr[index] = data;
    }
  
void pop() 
  {
     current--; 
  }
  
int size() 
  {
     return current; 
  }
  
int getcapacity() 
  {
     return capacity; 
  }
 
void print ()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < current; i++)
  cout << arr[i] << " ";
  cout << "\n";
}
 
void ClearArray (int *a, int n)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  a[i] = 0;
}
~Array()
{
  delete[] arr;
}
friend Array operator + (Array &p,int &z)
{
  arr[current] = z;
  current++;
}
Array& operator[] (const int index) 
{
    return arr[index];
}
Array& operator--()
{
    --current;
      return *this;
}
Array& operator--(int)
{
    current=current - 1;
    --(*this); 
    return *this; 
}
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Array &a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < current; i++)
}
};
int main() {
Array<int> a;
a.push(20);
a.push(43);
a.push(40);
a.push(60);
a.push(10);
a.push(30);
cout << "Number last element :" << a.size() << endl;
cout << "Array capacity equals :" << a.getcapacity() << endl;
cout << "Array's elements :";
a.print();
a.push(777,4);
a.print();
a.pop();
a.print();
--a;
a.print();
a--;
a.print();
return 0;
}
```

Сам код - это копия класса vector, все работает, кроме этих операторов.

Прошу помощи
Очень плохо понимаю это все

Comment: Сама идея использовать декремент для чего-то кроме декремента может нести в дальнейшем проблемы с пониманием смысла программы - вы скажете, что он удалает хвостовой элемент, я скажу, что он делает декремент всем элементам. Кто из нас будет прав в разгадке ребуса?

Comment: расскажите это создателям буста или Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычные функции ничего не знают о том, с каких объектом они работают. Поэтому, им нужно явно передать и использовать. Я поправил две функции и вроде как оно работает (но это можете сказать только Вы)

```
friend Array& operator + (Array &p,int z)
{
  p.arr[p.current] = z;//опасно, нужно проверять capacity
  p.current++;
  return p;
}
```

и позвать можно так

```
a = a + 1;
```

Но мне эта версия не нравится. Как только capacity закончится, будет выход за пределы. Я бы тут явно вызывал push (но эту имплементацию ещё нужно написать).

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Array &a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < a.current; i++) {
      out << a.arr[i] << ' ';
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: У меня почему-то после применения оператора вывода два раза выводится массив. А оператор + не получается вызвать(

Comment: с выводом не понял проблемы, а оператор + поправил

Comment: а как позвать вывод?
cout << "Array's elements :" << a; в этой строке два раза выводит массив на экран:

Comment: И еще вопросик : 
T& Array operator [] (const int index) 
{
    return arr[index];
}
Не работает оператор индексации, в чем беда?

Comment: а что должна возвращать эта функция? наверно элемент массива (точнее ссылку на него). А что она возвращает в Вашем случае? ссылку на массив? `T& operator[] (int index) 
{
    return arr[index];
}`